# Python Suds' MessagePlugin does not seem to be updating my output

Tags: python, xml, soap, xml-namespaces, suds

I am trying to use suds to make a request to a remote SOAP service. I need to set the namespace on the parameters thus:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:ns0="http://myemployer.com/"    xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header>
      <AuthHeader xmlns="http://myemployer.com/">
            <Token>blah</Token>
      </AuthHeader>
   </SOAP-ENV:Header>
   <ns1:Body>
      <ns0:AwardBadgesBatch>
          <ns0:badgeAwards>
              <AwardBadge>
                  <EnterpriseID>jhoov11</EnterpriseID>
                  ...
              </AwardBadge>
         </ns0:badgeAwards>
         <ns0:includeSuccessStatus>false</ns0:includeSuccessStatus>
      </ns0:AwardBadgesBatch>
   </ns1:Body>   
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Note the 'ns0' on both the badgeAwards and includeSuccessStatus elements. I also need to not have prefixes on the stuff inside badgeAwards.

I am using this code to make the request:

```
from suds.client import Client
from suds.sax.element import Element
from suds.sax.attribute import Attribute
from suds.plugin import MessagePlugin
import logging
logging.getLogger('suds.client').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logging.getLogger('suds.transport').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
url='https://myemployer.com/BadgingServices.asmx?wsdl'

c = Client(url)
t = c.service.Authenticate('blah')
t = t.Authenticate.Status.Token

header_root = Element('AuthHeader')
header_token = Element('Token').setText(t)
header_attribute = Attribute('xmlns', "http://myemployer.com/")
soap_header = header_root.insert(header_token)
soap_header.append(header_attribute)

class NamespaceFixer(MessagePlugin):
    ''' must add namespace prefix to all parameters '''
    def marshalled(self, context):
        body = context.envelope[1]
        for i in body[0]:
            i.setPrefix('ns0')
            print "******* element after setting prefix: %s ********" % i.plain()

nsf = NamespaceFixer()
c.set_options(soapheaders=soap_header, plugins=[nsf])

from suds.sax.element import Element

ba2 = Element('badgeAwards')
ba = Element('AwardBadge')
ba2.append(ba)
entid = Element('EnterpriseID').setText('jhoov11')
ba.append(entid)
...

includeSuccess = Element('includeSuccessStatus').setText('false')

c.service.AwardBadgesBatch(badgeAwards= ba2, includeSuccessStatus=includeSuccess)
```

Now when I do this, I see the xml text output before the marshall() call, and I see the output from that call:

```
******* element after setting prefix: <ns0:badgeAwards/> ********
******* element after setting prefix: <ns0:includeSuccessStatus/> ********
```

but the folks on the other end insist (insist!) that the prefix is not set on those elements when they receive it.

Two questions come to mind:

1. am I doing something wrong in my MessagePlugin?
2. is there a way to display the final modified XML text before it gets sent off? I think I'm setting it but there's only so much I can say to them when I can't see the final full text I'm sending.

**EDIT:**

```
c.last_sent().plain()
u'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:ns0="http://pebble.searshc.com/" xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">

<SOAP-ENV:Header><AuthHeader xmlns="http://myemployer.com/"><Token>blah</Token></AuthHeader></SOAP-ENV:Header>
<ns1:Body><ns0:AwardBadgesBatch><ns0:badgeAwards/><ns0:includeSuccessStatus/></ns0:AwardBadgesBatch></ns1:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>'
```

so badgeAwards and includeSuccessStatus are being sent empty. ???

**EDIT**: trying factory. This wsdl is odd (to me)--it defines the call itself as a type, thus:

```
<s:element name="AwardBadgesBatch">
  <s:complexType>
    <s:sequence>
      <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="badgeAwards">
         <s:complexType mixed="true">
           <s:sequence>
              <s:any/>
           </s:sequence>
         </s:complexType>
      </s:element>
      <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="includeSuccessStatus" type="s:boolean"/>
    </s:sequence>
  </s:complexType>
</s:element>


...

<wsdl:operation name="AwardBadgesBatch">
  <soap:operation soapAction="http://pebble.searshc.com/AwardBadgesBatch" style="document"/>
  <wsdl:input>
    <soap:body use="literal"/>
    <soap:header message="tns:AwardBadgesBatchAuthHeader" part="AuthHeader" use="literal"/>
  </wsdl:input>
  <wsdl:output>
    <soap:body use="literal"/>
    <soap:header message="tns:AwardBadgesBatchAuthHeader" part="AuthHeader" use="literal"/>
  </wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
```

It does not define an AwardBadge type. So I just make my AwardBadge thus:

```
ba = Element('AwardBadge')

entid = Element('EnterpriseID').setText('jhoov11')
ba.append(entid)
btype = Element('badgeTypeID').setText('30')
ba.append(btype)
startdate = Element('startDate').setText('2013-8-22')
ba.append(startdate)
enddate = Element('endDate').setText('9999-12-31')
ba.append(enddate)
isdeleted = Element('isDeleted').setText('0')
ba.append(isdeleted)
```

and I set the values on my call

```
call = c.factory.create('AwardBadgesBatch')
call.badgeAwards= [ba]
call.includeSuccessStatus= False
```

and I call the service

```
c.service.AwardBadgesBatch(call)
```

and get some errors. When I look at what I sent I see

```
c.last_sent().plain()
u'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:ns0="http://myemployer.com/" xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <SOAP-ENV:Header>
      <AuthHeader xmlns="http://myemployer.com/"><Token>blah</Token></AuthHeader>
  </SOAP-ENV:Header>
  <ns1:Body>
     <ns0:AwardBadgesBatch>
        <ns0:badgeAwards>
           <AwardBadge/>
           <ns0:includeSuccessStatus>false</ns0:includeSuccessStatus>
         </ns0:badgeAwards>
         <ns0:includeSuccessStatus/>
     </ns0:AwardBadgesBatch>
  </ns1:Body>
  </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>'
```

So, three problems:

1. AwardBadge is empty.
2. the includeSuccessStatus is duplicated, one inside badgeAwards, where it doesn't belong.
3. the includeSuccessStatus that's in the right place is empty.

It doesn't make a difference whether I set badgeAwards to ba or [ba].

Any more insight?

Answer (score 0):

Suds provides factory for service types - client.service.factory.create(type_name). That gives you python object. Here is demonstration, may be you can adapt it to your case:

```
...
client = Client(...)
award = client.factory.create("ns0:AwardBadgesBatch")
award.includeSuccessStatus = True
...
```

Suds has two nice methods - client.last_sent() and client.last_received(). Using them after request you can see what exactly did you send and received. Also, you can know a lot about service printing suds client:

```
client = Client(...)
print client
```

Comment: ok, so you're saying use client.factory.create instead of using the  methods suds makes from wsdl?

Comment: award = c.factory.create('ns0:AwardBadgesBatch')
award.includeSuccessStatus='false'
award.badgeAwards= ba
c.service.AwardBadgesBatch(award)

Comment: so trying setting award.awardBadges to the element above, and likewise award. includeSuccessStatus, I get an empty includeSuccessStatus, which fails. Also an empty AwardBadge.

Comment: Not methods, but types. Here is documentation https://fedorahosted.org/suds/wiki/Documentation#FACTORY

Comment: So it appears that the type/method confusion here is material--this WSDL defines a method as a type, and just instantiating that type and passing it to the method produces bad results, as we see with the edit above. I can't change this WSDL. I'm looking for how suds handles this. if you or anyone has any directions you can point me in, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a bug in suds 0.4. Any updates done in MessagePlugins are simply not applied and the original message is send instead.

You can fix it by patching client.py in suds:

```
--- python2.7/site-packages/suds/client.py Sun Jan 08 16:58:36 2017 +0100
+++ client.py Thu Oct 05 11:04:20 2017 +0200
@@ -631,7 +631,8 @@
             else:
                 soapenv = soapenv.plain()
             soapenv = soapenv.encode('utf-8')
-            plugins.message.sending(envelope=soapenv)
+            ctx = plugins.message.sending(envelope=soapenv)
+            soapenv = ctx.envelope
             request = Request(location, soapenv)
             request.headers = self.headers()
             reply = transport.send(request)
```

Another option might be to switch to maybe switch to the [jurko fork of suds](https://bitbucket.org/jurko/suds/overview), which also fixes this bug. However, I haven't tried that option myself.

The problem is also mentioned in this question: [Suds Client ignores modification done by plugins into sending method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40573085/suds-client-ignores-modification-done-by-plugins-into-sending-method)