# Suds Client ignores modification done by plugins into sending method

Tags: python-2.7, suds

I am trying to use a plugin doing modification on sending.

Modification are done, but suds sends the soap before the modification.

After a long search into my plugin, I finish by looking the suds sources.

Into the client.py file, the `send` function calls the plugins:

```
 plugins.message.sending(envelope=soapenv)
```

but after this call soapenv is still as previous.

As plugins return the ctx, I patch with

```
res = plugins.message.sending(envelope=soapenv)
soapenv = res.envelope
```

and it is now working as expected. As soapenv is a string, I think Python pass it by value so I don't get how it can work without this kind of patch.

Why I need this patch ? What I am doing wrong ?

Version used:

Python 2.7.9 (default, Jun 29 2016, 13:08:31) 
[GCC 4.9.2] on linux2

suds (0.4)

Comment: Seems to be a bug from suds, has been fixed here: https://bitbucket.org/jurko/suds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sud should not be used, jurko fork is better and fix this issue